# How does one modify headers in Ruby to replicate Firefox?

Tags: ruby, http, header

I'm trying to create an automated tool and I'd like my script to simulate Firefox-like headers. Currently doing an HTTP get will have the minimal number of headers. I believe method, host, and accept.

This is the method I'm using right now:

```
def fetch(url_str, limit = 10)
    raise ArguementError, 'HTTP redirect too deep' if limit == 0

    res = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url_str))

    case res
    when Net::HTTPSuccess then
        $dpage += res.body
    when Net::HTTPRedirection then 
        $dpage += fetch(res['location'], limit - 1)
    else
        puts res.error!
    end
end
```

How can I change this to more headers? Or even modify the "Accept" that's already there?

I've tried a method using "Net::HTTP::Get.add_field" but it resulted in "Bad Request" response from the host.

When I analyzed the packets I could see why. The headers were not in the proper order. Not in the order that I was adding them in my code.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into something like [Typhoeus](https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus) which has a [nice API](http://justinvadakkan.blogspot.com/2011/04/setting-user-agent-in-typhoeu.html) for handling these things.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'd like to stick to Ruby's native libraries. The capabilities are there but I just don't know how they work and couldn't find anything with enough details in the ruby docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can give [mechanize](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/) a try.